# Can the XML serializer output empty tags?

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I am using the XML serializer. I would like it to convert all my object's elements, but it only seems to output tags when there is a value.

How can I get it to output empty tags?

Comment: What is the specific scenario you have in mind? null object? empty collection? what?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at a couple of options on how to solve this problem here:

http://danshultz.blogspot.com/2008/02/xmlserialization-nullempty-elements.html

Comment: This works great for strings, but what about a more complex type?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, then not without implementing `IXmlSerializable` (which is *not* fun; don't go there). There are things like the `ShouldSerialize*` / `*Specified` patterns, but it *still* won't write something for `null`s (even if you return true).